# using jpa with legacy hbm files

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is there a way to use existing legacy hibernate  mapping files (hbms) with spring jpa `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` .
configuration :

- Hibernate Version : 4.2.5.Final ,
- Spring version : 4.0.3.RELEASE .

Running in Tomcat 7 servlet container.

I agree that this is unreasonable but the project manager whants to migrate the code to spring and hibernate 4  and not the hbm files.

I tested the application with jpa annotated entities and it works great. but , it I try to use hbm it wont. I ended up writing somothing like this but didn't work.

```
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("META-INF/persistence.xml");
```

and in persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="easysApp" >
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

  <properties>
    <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="hbm"/>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

then i get this stack trace :

```
WARN 2014-09-19 10:59:00,148 (InputStreamZippedJarVisitor.java:66) - HHH015010: Unable to find file (ignored): jndi:/localhost/Migration
ava.io.FileNotFoundException: jndi:/localhost/Migration
       at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:389)
       at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.InputStreamZippedJarVisitor.doProcessElements(InputStreamZippedJarVisitor.java:62)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.getMatchingEntries(AbstractJarVisitor.java:149)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getFilesInJar(NativeScanner.java:192)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:506)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:861)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:606)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
```

Comment: You should only need your hbm files. The class element if for classes with the `@Entity` annotation.

Comment: Try removing the mapping and class elements and a property. The name of the property is `hibernate.archive.autodetection` and put `hbm,class` as a value. Together with adding `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` that should scan your path for hbm files and for class files containing `@Entity` annotations.

Comment: I tried this but detection failed (without error in console) . I mention that i don' have any class with @Entity annotation

Comment: Did you try both including the `exclude-unlisted-classes`? As people often forget that that by default is `true`!

Comment: Yes , i put it at false and nothing detected !

Comment: did i have to mention wich package to scan or anything like that ?

Comment: NOrmally it should scan all packages. You also did the `ibernate.archive.autodetection`? You could try specifying only `hbm` and crank up the logging for hibernate to debug.

Comment: Could you please add the framework versions you are using to the post.

Comment: first thanks for your reply , i tried what you suggest and it is still ko ; i Have springframework version 4.0.3.RELEASE and hibernate 4.3.0.Final

Comment: I m debbugging spring sources . I think at a certain point he find's the class (User in my case ) but he didn't put it because it doesn't match one of three AnnotationTypeFilter (Entity , Embeddable,MappedSuperclass) any idea ?

Comment: It has little use in debug spring code as the issue with Hibernate. As mentioned could you please add the version info to your post and also the configuration you have (at least the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`).

Comment: Hi, I mentioned frameworks versions in previous comment . and this is how i configured the jpa factory : LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.business");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("META-INF/persistence.xml");

Comment: I'm going to repeat myself again please add that to the post... That way all the information is in a single location instead of in comments. Hence my repeated request for you to modify your initial post (next to that for posting code you want to use code formatting).

Comment: The `packagesToScan` isn't doing anything because you don't have `@Entity` classes. Remove it (as it might interfere with the default scanning in Hibernate itself).

Comment: thx , post updated. I removed the setPackageToScan ligne . therefore there's an exption occured : FileNotFoundException . it seems that hibernate tries to scann jar directories and it fails java.io.FileNotFoundException: jndi:/localhost/Migration. any ideas

Comment: Please add the full stack trace to the post (as well as the other info) just seeing a snippet isn't informative enough.

Comment: Also why do you need to move to JPA? Why not just move to hibernate4? Saves you a migration of your data access layer from plain hibernate to JPA.

Comment: I updated the original post . please take a look . Do you think using hibernate4 instead jpa make it easier ?

Comment: Plain hibernate is well just plain hibernate. So that works with either annotations or hbm files. And it should work just as hibernate3 did. It would be a matter of using the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` from the `hibernate4` package instead of `hibernate3` and also all the other classes and you should be good to go. So I don't really get the migration to JPA if the only intend was to update to hibernate4.

Comment: Another thing is that your persistence.xml is 1.0 whereas you are using a jpa2 provider (so it should read 2.0 instead). The stack trace is only a warning it shouldn't be deadly for the startup of your application. Have you tried putting hibernate logging to debug or trace and figure out what is happening inside.

Comment: THANKS @M.Deinum , i ended up not using jpa config and falled back to hibernate specific implementation and that works fine .

Comment: @Deinum, and author - Just picking up this old thread as I am also in similar situation to upgrade legacy app to spring4/hibernate5 stack. My application is giving errors with all legacy hbm mappings. Is there any setting/config I can use to make these legacy hbms work with latest JPA2.0?

Comment: @SamiJmii, do you have any working example for the usecase worked above? Hibernate without jpa configuration.

Comment: @San Im sorry , it has been a long time since i used hibernate. could not help